# Display vat value in text box

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know why I'm getting a value NaN in the vat input box? When I enter a value of qty it always gives me a NaN value.

```
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function(){
    var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
    var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
    var vat = 0.12;

    var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2));

    $('#sales_vat').val((sales_total * vat).toFixed(2));
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yv6zks1g/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `sales_total` is the element itself, (not the value). you should add another `val()` at the end to get the value.

```js
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function(){
    var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
    var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
    var vat = 0.12;

    var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2)).val();

    $('#sales_vat').val((sales_total * vat).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sales_qty" type="text" placeholder="sales_qty" />
<input id="sales_sub_total" type="text" placeholder="sales_sub_total" />
<input id="sales_total" type="text" placeholder="sales_total" />
<input id="sales_vat" type="text" placeholder="sales_vat"/>
```

Comment: Can you check this one please? I will display the amount due when the user enters the quantity. I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: (sales_total + sales_vat).toFixed is not a function" https://jsfiddle.net/yv6zks1g/1/

Comment: @J.Wujeck That's because when you multiply two string numbers in JS, the JS engine will convert them to numbers. but in summation, it assumes them strings and concatenates them. so the `sales_total + sales_vat` is a string like 11.000.55 (string concatination of 11.00 and 0.55) which is not a correct number to be fixed.

Comment: What should I do? Can you help me?

Comment: Just change `sales_total + sales_vat` to `parseFloat(sales_total) + parseFloat(sales_vat)`

Comment: This what I did: But it returns NaN value in textbox: $('#sales_amount_due').val((parseFloat(sales_total) + parseFloat(sales_vat)).toFixed(2));

Comment: I updated your fiddle and it seems it is working properly: https://jsfiddle.net/73qtamse/

Answer (score 0):

i think its because of the  `var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2));` line. 
instead of `$('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2));` 
add `var sales_total = (qty * sub_total).toFixed(2);`

Answer (score 0):

As in these two lines you are parsing float value from your input elements,

```
var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
```

You need to set your inputs like these,

```
<input id="sales_qty" type="number" /> 
<input id="sales_sub_total" type="number" />
```

So that it is not possible to enter anything other than number. This will get you rid of the NaN problem.

Also you need to put

```
var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2)).val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are not getting the real value of `sales total input` and you are just assigning a new value for it. On this line

```
var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2));
```

To fix it you have to get again the value of `sales total input` by using the `val() method`. Your code should look like this

```
$('#sales_qty').keyup(function(){
    var qty = parseFloat($('#sales_qty').val()) || 0;
    var sub_total = parseFloat($('#sales_sub_total').val()) || 0;
    var vat = 0.12;
    
    $('#sales_total').val((qty * sub_total).toFixed(2)); // assign the value
    var sales_total = $('#sales_total').val()  // grab the value

    $('#sales_vat').val((sales_total * vat).toFixed(2));
});
```